# Adding Case in two sub queries returning null on subtract

Tags: sql, .net, database

I have two tables, both have `qty` column, I want to subtract `issued_donated_items` from `donated_items`. It works fine until there is not a record in `issued_donated_items` then my query returns null

```
SELECT 
(
(SELECT Sum(quantity) AS tQty  FROM donated_items WHERE item_id=4)

-

(SELECT Sum(quantity_issued) AS issueQty  FROM issued_donated_items WHERE item_id=4)

)AS total
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest moving the subqueries to the `from` clause and using `coalesce()`:

```
SELECT (COALESCE(di.QTY, 0) - COALESCE(idi.issueQTY, 0)
       ) AS total
FROM (SELECT Sum(quantity) AS tQty FROM donated_items WHERE item_id = 4) di CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT Sum(quantity_issued) AS issueQty FROM issued_donated_items WHERE item_id = 4) idi;
```

This makes it easy to re-use the values if you, for instance, want to see the two numbers as well as their difference.

Answer (score 1):

Use **isnull()** like this:

```
SELECT 
(
(SELECT Sum(isnull(quantity,0)) AS tQty  FROM donated_items WHERE item_id=4)

-

(SELECT Sum(isnull(quantity_issued,0)) AS issueQty  FROM issued_donated_items WHERE item_id=4)

)AS total
```

For ANSI standard SQL use **coalesce()** instead of **isnull()**.

Comment: I can understand the answer but not  the upvote, because this will not solve the OP's problem.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: It's not like OP explained the problem with precision. I made a guess, you made a guess, and maybe one of us is correct.

Comment: The OP did explain the relevant portions.  Your code will still return `NULL` when `issued_donated_items` has no matching rows.

Comment: @GordonLinoff you are right, I am still getting `NULL`

Comment: @PieterGeerkens . . . In case you haven't figured it out yet, your query handles `NULL` values stored in the tables.  It does not handle the case where the subquery returns no rows.